# How to wait for a background function to finish before calling another one in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, background

I will try to explain briefly what the situation is.
I am building a quiz app and I wanted it to work mainly using the internet, but also to work for a while when the user is disconnected. The older code I was using was made only with synchronous queries, it was taking more time than what I expected. So i decided to reformulate it. 
The situation I projected is the following:

- When my user selects a **subject** the app will **synchronously** get 1 question for each **subsubject** in order to be ready for my user click and to be faster.
- After getting this first question, the app would then get another 4 (or how much is needed to complete 5) for each of the **subsubjects** **asynchronously**, while the user is occupied answering the first question that was presented to him.
- Finally, the app would save the objects in the local datastore, so that the user can answer 5 questions for each subsubject when he is not connected.

Here is my code:

```
func getQuestionsRemotelyandSave (subsubject:String?, subject:String?, arrayOfSubsubjects:[String]?) {
    self.getFromUserDefaults()
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
            if self.needsToGetQuestions == true {
                let user = PFUser.currentUser()
                var query = PFQuery(className: "Questions")
                query.whereKey("answeredBy", equalTo: user)
                query.whereKey("grade", equalTo: user["grade"])

                if subsubject != nil && subject == nil {
                    query.whereKey("subsubject", equalTo: subsubject)
                    query.limit = 2
                    let array = query.findObjects()
                    for item in array {
                        let object = item as PFObject
                        var QuestionToPin = PFObject(className: "Questions")
                        QuestionToPin["Question"] = object["Question"] as String
                        QuestionToPin["rightAnswer"] = object ["rightAnswer"] as String
                        QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer1"] = object ["wrongAnswer1"] as String
                        QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer2"] = object ["wrongAnswer2"] as String
                        QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer3"] = object ["wrongAnswer3"] as String
                        QuestionToPin["grade"] = object["grade"] as String
                        QuestionToPin["subject"] = object ["subject"] as String
                        QuestionToPin["subsubject"] = object ["subsubject"] as String
                        QuestionToPin["feedback"] = object ["feedback"] as? String
                        QuestionToPin["shortFeedback1"] = object ["shortFeedback1"] as? String
                        QuestionToPin["shortFeedback2"] = object ["shortFeedback2"] as? String
                        QuestionToPin["shortFeedback3"] = object ["shortFeedback3"] as? String
                        QuestionToPin.pin()
                    }
                    query.limit = 3
                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            let questions = objects as [PFObject]
                            var QuestionsToPin = [PFObject]()
                            for object in questions {
                                var QuestionToPin = PFObject(className: "Questions")
                                QuestionToPin["Question"] = object["Question"] as String
                                QuestionToPin["rightAnswer"] = object ["rightAnswer"] as String
                                QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer1"] = object ["wrongAnswer1"] as String
                                QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer2"] = object ["wrongAnswer2"] as String
                                QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer3"] = object ["wrongAnswer3"] as String
                                QuestionToPin["grade"] = object["grade"] as String
                                QuestionToPin["subject"] = object ["subject"] as String
                                QuestionToPin["subsubject"] = object ["subsubject"] as String
                                QuestionToPin["feedback"] = object ["feedback"] as? String
                                QuestionToPin["shortFeedback1"] = object ["shortFeedback1"] as? String
                                QuestionToPin["shortFeedback2"] = object ["shortFeedback2"] as? String
                                QuestionToPin["shortFeedback3"] = object ["shortFeedback3"] as? String
                                QuestionToPin.pinInBackground()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }

                if subsubject == nil && subject != nil {
                    var firstTime = true
                    var semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
                    query.limit = 1
                    for item in arrayOfSubsubjects! {
                        if item != "Todas as matérias" {
                            var query3 = PFQuery(className: "Questions")
                            query3.fromLocalDatastore()
                            query3.whereKey("subsubject", equalTo: item)
                            let count = query3.countObjects()
                            if count == 0 {
                                query.whereKey("subsubject", equalTo: item)

                                let array:NSArray = query.findObjects()
                                for item in array {
                                    let object = item as PFObject
                                    var QuestionToPin = PFObject(className: "Questions")
                                    QuestionToPin["Question"] = object["Question"] as String
                                    QuestionToPin["rightAnswer"] = object ["rightAnswer"] as String
                                    QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer1"] = object ["wrongAnswer1"] as String
                                    QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer2"] = object ["wrongAnswer2"] as String
                                    QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer3"] = object ["wrongAnswer3"] as String
                                    QuestionToPin["grade"] = object["grade"] as String
                                    QuestionToPin["subject"] = object ["subject"] as String
                                    QuestionToPin["subsubject"] = object ["subsubject"] as String
                                    QuestionToPin["feedback"] = object ["feedback"] as? String
                                    QuestionToPin["shortFeedback1"] = object ["shortFeedback1"] as? String
                                    QuestionToPin["shortFeedback2"] = object ["shortFeedback2"] as? String
                                    QuestionToPin["shortFeedback3"] = object ["shortFeedback3"] as? String
                                    QuestionToPin.pin()
                                }

                            }

                            if count > 0 {
                                var limit = 5 - count
                                if limit < 0 {
                                    limit = 0
                                }
                                query.limit = limit
                                if firstTime == false {
                                    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
                                }
                                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                                    if error == nil {
                                        let questions = objects as [PFObject]
                                        for object in questions {
                                            var QuestionToPin = PFObject(className: "Questions")
                                            QuestionToPin["Question"] = object["Question"] as String
                                            QuestionToPin["rightAnswer"] = object ["rightAnswer"] as String
                                            QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer1"] = object ["wrongAnswer1"] as String
                                            QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer2"] = object ["wrongAnswer2"] as String
                                            QuestionToPin["wrongAnswer3"] = object ["wrongAnswer3"] as String
                                            QuestionToPin["grade"] = object["grade"] as String
                                            QuestionToPin["subject"] = object ["subject"] as String
                                            QuestionToPin["subsubject"] = object ["subsubject"] as String
                                            QuestionToPin["feedback"] = object ["feedback"] as? String
                                            QuestionToPin["shortFeedback1"] = object ["shortFeedback1"] as? String
                                            QuestionToPin["shortFeedback2"] = object ["shortFeedback2"] as? String
                                            QuestionToPin["shortFeedback3"] = object ["shortFeedback3"] as? String

                                            QuestionToPin.pinInBackground()
                                        }
                                        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
                                        firstTime = false
                                    }
                                })

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
      }
  }
```

The problem I'm facing is that I cant request multiple asynchronous functions from Parse. What I thought was maybe waiting for an asynchronous function to finish before the other one starts, but I wanted it to happen without the user having to wait. Is there a way of doing it?

Thank you.

Comment: Thats very interesting I was thinking of downloading all the questions and answers into core data so even though we lost connection the user still could continue

Comment: Hi Lamar, I'm not downloading all the questions for a main reason:
- Some types of users are able to submit questions. That way, remote connection is my best choice, instead of updating the app every time.

Comment: I am not saying to download all the data at once, what i am saying lets say they are answering 10 questions: so you could download the questions and answers for this session then you could do all the checks on core data then once they finish you clear the database then redownload new data from parse into the core data

Comment: I have another method that gets a new question for that subsubject each time the user answers a question, if he is connected. I don't know, i am trying to minimize the wait time with all my efforts, but if i can't get this to work, I will need another way...